# nextjs httpService send post with variable data to API

Tags: next.js, axios

I am looking to call an end point on https://www.one-dc.com/ao/ from nestjs.
I am currently getting the error message:
data 13 - XML tags should be given in the POST variable "data"

```
const { data } = await firstValueFrom(
  this.httpService
    .post(process.env.EDC_ORDER_URL, { data: xmlOutput })
    .pipe(
      catchError((error: AxiosError) => {
        this.logger.log('Axios error')
        this.logger.error(error.response.data);
        throw 'An error happened!';
      }),
    ),
);
console.log(data);
```

The response is coming from the

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using:

```
const url = require('url');
const params = new url.URLSearchParams({
  data: xmlOutput,
});
const { data } = await firstValueFrom(
  this.httpService.post(process.env.EDC_ORDER_URL, params.toString()).pipe(
    catchError((error: AxiosError) => {
      this.logger.error(error.response.data);
      throw 'An error happened!';
    }),
  ),
);
```